# Get value/state from component dynamically generated on react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ui-kitten

i have one question...

Within a project, I have a checkbox list that is generated from a JSON.
What is the best way for me to recover which checkboxes were checked?

*Observation: I use **UI Kitten** for the Layout*

**Code Details**
Function that generates the checkbox

```
export const ExtraCheck = (props) => {
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(props.padrao);
  return (
    <CheckBox style={{ marginTop: 4, marginBottom: 4 }} checked={checked} onChange={nextChecked => setChecked(nextChecked)}>
      {props.nome}
    </CheckBox>
  )
}
```

From a JSON I call the component to be presented on the screen with the necessary data.

```
<ExtraCheck nome="CHECK 1" />
<ExtraCheck nome="CHECK 2" />
<ExtraCheck nome="CHECK 3" />
```

But I don't know how I can recover the checkbox it was checked, Can someone help me please?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Share your complete code

Comment: Use an identifier for each checkbox component and use a callback function as a prop to ExtraCheck component to keep track of check changes